# Jquery script changes are not working in IE 11 browser after deploying using IIS

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, internet-explorer-11

I have made changes in one of the script file in my project which is developed in C#.net(It is developed in .net 4.0) .When i tested in localhost it is working fine.After deploying modified file using IIS changes are not reflecting in IE 11 but i could able to see the reflected changes in IE 9 and Google Chrome.Please help me with this.

Comment: clear browser cache. it may help.

Comment: No..It doesnt work for me.Any other solution?